# Имя Mileena на русском.

Tags: общие-вопросы

Существует персонаж по имени Mileena. Убедительной аргументации в том, как следует произносить данное имя, мне найти не удалось. 
В английском первоисточнике оно произносится как "Милина", в то время, как русскоязычное большинство использует имя "Милена", очевидно, по аналогии, с существующим славянским именем.

Отсюда вопрос, как с точки зрения правил русского языка, следует поступать с этим именем? Верно ли употреблять славянский эквивалент или же имя должно оставаться неизменным, не смотря на очевидное созвучие? (вопрос вызван тем, что, к примеру, американцы, без зазрения совести заменяют "Иоанн Павел II" на "Джон Пол II", а мы, в свою очередь, заменяем привычным "Иоанн Павел" оригинальное " Ioannes Paulus". Так же, русскому языку характерно менять "Ка́йсар" на "Цезарь" и тому подобное).

В этой связи хочется уточнить, что говорят правила о изменении имён и, в конечном итоге, правильным станет использование варианта "Милина" или "Милена"?

Comment: «русскому языку характерно» это не по-русски.  Характерно для кого-либо или для чего-либо, свойственно кому-л., чему-л.,  присуще кому-л., чему-л..
Не «о изменении», а «об изменении»
«аргументации в том» - такое управление мне встретилось впервые!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы делаете перевод с английского, нужно знать происхождение носителя этого имени. Если по сюжету произведения персонаж приехал из другой страны (и он родом оттуда), то исходить нужно не из английского написания или произношения, а из правил транскрипции имён собственных с языка той страны, откуда персонаж приехал. Подробные правила есть, напр., для транскрипции с французского, и очень строгие правила существуют для китайских собственных имён (система Палладия). Если имя дано в англоязычной стране её постоянными жителями (напр. в США в год появляется ~80 девочек по имени Mileena), то скорее, "Милина", как оно пишется и произносится по-английски. Если же речь о девушке, приехавшей из Словакии, то возможно, Милена (хотя в таком случае характернее был бы прямой перенос в английский написания 'Milena'). Контекст произведения может подсказать окончательное решение (есть ли в сюжете "славянский след" - мог ли быть заложен соотв. смысл в имя).

Answer (score 2):

Имена собственные в принципе не переводятся, но существуют традиции их передачи средствами другого языка. Если язык, с которого переводят, и язык, на который переводят, пользуются одним и тем же алфавитом, то никаких проблем не возникает. При передаче названий и имен, написанных латиницей, с помощью кириллицы, используются правила транслитерации (транскрипция – это совсем другое). Традиции транслитерации были разными в различные периоды времени. Например, переводчики 18-19 века не стеснялись давать иностранным персонажам русские имена (в этой традиции работал Вл. Набоков, когда переводил на русский «Алису в стране чудес», он назвал героиню Аней). В 20 веке вошло в моду подражание иностранному «прононсу»: бывший Евгений, если он был англичанином, превратился в Юджина, а если французом – в Эжена.  В моем издании Шерлока Холмса (1960-х годов) нет доктора Ватсона, есть доктор Уотсон.  Видимо, в более ранних изданиях использовались другие правила транслитерации, к тому же переводчиков с английского в 19 веке было мало и английских авторов часто переводили с французского или немецкого. Главная ошибка, которую может сделать переводчик при передаче иностранных имен, это нечаянно переименовать какое-либо известное историческое лицо. Например, нынешний принц Уэльский именуется у нас Чарльзом, а его предшественников с тем же именем у нас принято называть Карлами. И называть их Чарльзами было бы ошибкой: необходимо соблюдать традицию, чтобы не запутать читателя.

Comment: транскрипция – это совсем другое

Передачу собств. имён средствами другого языка называют Практической Транскрипцией.   

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Практическая_транскрипция
Транслитерация (передача написания) может входить систему ПТ для двух языков, но действует с учётом фонетической транскрипции, системы исключений и пр.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Англо-русская_практическая_транскрипция
Транслитерация не всегда применима: в китайско-русской ПТ имеет место приблизительная передача фонем, а не символов. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Транскрипционная_система_Палладия

Comment: >транскрипция – это совсем другое<
Передачу собств. имён средствами другого языка называют Практической Транскрипцией. 
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Практическая_транскрипция
Транслитерация (передача написания) может входить систему ПТ для двух языков, но действует с учётом фонетической транскрипции, системы исключений и пр.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Англо-русская_практическая_транскрипция
Транслитерация не всегда применима: в китайско-русской ПТ имеет место приблизительная передача фонем, а не символов. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Транскрипционная_система_Палладия

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы делаете перевод с английского, нужно знать происхождение носителя этого имени. Если по сюжету произведения персонаж приехал из другой страны (и он родом оттуда), то исходить нужно не из английского написания или произношения, а из правил транскрипции имён собственных с языка той страны, откуда персонаж приехал. Подробные правила есть, напр., для транскрипции с французского, и очень строгие правила существуют для китайских собственных имён (система Палладия). Если имя дано в англоязычной стране её постоянными жителями (напр. в США в год появляется ~80 девочек по имени Mileena), то скорее, "Милина", как оно пишется и произносится по-английски. Если же речь о девушке, приехавшей из Словакии, то возможно, Милена (хотя в таком случае характернее был бы прямой перенос в английский написания 'Milena'). Контекст произведения может подсказать окончательное решение (есть ли в сюжете "славянский след" - мог ли быть заложен соотв. смысл в имя).